# Is "execute as" mandatory in natively compiled stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, in-memory-database

I noticed that all examples (that I've seen) of **natively compiled** stored procedures (in SQL Server) are defined using `EXECUTE AS OWNER`.

[For example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/native-compilation-advisor?view=sql-server-ver15#code-sample):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertOrderXTP]  
    @id INT, 
    @date DATETIME2, 
    @status TINYINT  
WITH NATIVE_COMPILATION, SCHEMABINDING, EXECUTE AS OWNER  
AS...
```

We started getting the following error while trying to execute natively compiled stored procedures we created with `EXECUTE AS OWNER`:

> Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user ...

This make sense because we had other un-related technical issue with the user that created those procedures.

Since we never used `EXECUTE AS ..` in regular ("interpreted") procedures, I tried removing it from the natively compiled stored procedure and it seems to to be working just fine.

But as I mentioned, it contrast from all the examples I've seen, and I couldn't find any relevant documentation that elaborates on this issue.

1. Must a natively compiled stored procedures be created with `EXECUTE AS OWNER...`"?
2. Is there a benefit to creating natively compiled stored procedures with `EXECUTE AS OWNER...` that doesn't exist in regular (interpreted) stored procedures?
3. Where can I find explicit documentation about this issue?

Comment: `Where can I find explicit documentation` - in the [explicit documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax)? The grammar has `EXECUTE AS` in brackets, so it's optional; then https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#execute-as-clause further explains there are no restrictions starting from v2016. There are no benefits as it's an access control feature, not a performance feature.

Comment: 10x @GSerg (:
Regarding my 2 and 3 questions - do you have any clue on why most (if not all) of microsoft examples of natively compiled storage procedures includes "EXECUTE AS..." but examples of regular procedure doen't? This fact is what making me wonder if there is more to it.

Comment: @Amstaf Because the examples were probably written a long time ago, and nobody went back to find them all and update them, primarily because _unless you have an unrelated issue with the specified account_ (that could also be solved by transferring ownership of the object), or really care about character  count, what benefit does going and removing all of them offer? Remember that some people reading the documentation and viewing those examples are themselves still using a version where the execute as reference _was_ necessary.

Comment: I assume that you're looking for a solution to the "Could not obtain information" error you're seeing. My guess is that either the schema or the database is owned by an invalid Windows account. I've seen this sort of thing when the db was created by someone no longer at the organization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a historical limitation that is no longer required as of SQL Server 2016.

In the [documentation for CREATE PROCEDURE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#execute-as-clause), we have this note:

> For natively compiled stored procedures, starting SQL Server 2016 (13.x) and in Azure SQL Database, there are no limitations on the EXECUTE AS clause. In SQL Server 2014 (12.x) the SELF, OWNER, and 'user_name' clauses are supported with natively compiled stored procedures.

Then on [the separate page about EXECUTE AS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/execute-as-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) there is this:

> CALLER is the default for all modules except queues, and is the same as SQL Server 2005 (9.x) behavior.

Put those two things together, and we find that omitting the EXECUTE AS clause on a natively compiled stored procedure in SQL Server 2014 would have defaulted to an unsupported option. So all examples of natively compiled stored procedures which predate SQL Server 2016 would have needed an explicit EXECUTE AS clause to compile successfully.